# Relative persistence unit inject?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have a Persistence.xml with multiple persistence-unit definition file exists.

I want to inject unit EntityManager object, according to the user who entered the system.

Is it possible?

```
@PersistenceContext (unitName = myUnit)
```

In this use, I get a warning: "attribute value must be constant"

Application Frameworks: JSF 2.1 & Spring 3.0.2

Persistence layer: JPA

Answer (score 2):

Can you use CDI? You could write a little class which gets injected with all the different contexts, then supplies them to your classes through a producer method which does some logic. Bit like this:

```
public class PersistenceContext {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myUnit") private EntityManager myEm;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="yourUnit") private EntityManager yourEm;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(InjectionPoint ip) {
        if (USER IS ME) {
            return myEm;
        }
        else if (USER IS YOU) {
            return yourEm;
        }
        else {
            NOW PANIC AND FREAK OUT
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just write classes like this:

```
public class FeedReamer {
    @Inject private EntityManager em;
}
```

And everything will magically happen right (possibly?).

If you don't want to hardcode the names of the persistence units in the class, then instead of relying on injection, you may be able to get the entity manager factories explicitly:

```
    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String persistenceUnitName = somehowDeterminePersistenceUnitName();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

However, although this method will work in a J2SE application, [Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String%29) is not guaranteed to work in J2EE. Footnote 42 in the spec (the EJB 3.0 persistence spec, at least) says:

> Use of these Java SE bootstrapping APIs may be supported in Java EE containers; however, support for such use is not required.

In addition, i believe that creating a new EntityManagerFactory can be quite slow; you might find you needed to cache the results of the lookups. I believe it should be safe to hold on to an EntityManagerFactory for a long time, and to access it from multiple threads (but i'm not certain).

Comment: I think it's the right direction. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if Spring doesn't bring its own implementation of the `@Inject` and other annotations. Wonder how it will cooperate...

Comment: Ah, i missed that you were using Spring, sorry. I'm sure Spring has its own equivalent of @Produces - you should be able to use that to implement the same pattern.

Comment: Hi Tom Anderson.

Suggested method, when a fixed number of unit available.

The number of unit is not stable on my system, can be increased at any time, and I do not want to interfere with the java.

Comment: The changes you would need to make to the code would be very minor; i would suggest you just do that. However, i have added a suggestion for how you might be able to do this without hardcoding all the persistence unit names.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, Java annotation attributes must be constant values, not references to variables. This is a limitation in the Java languages, not JPA. You'll need to find a different way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Final variables could not figure out this problem.

Can you suggest me a different can be found?

Comment: I want to say
    private String unit = "myUnit";
    private final String unitNanme = unit;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName=unitNanme)
    private EntityManager em;

Comment: Yes, I know what you're trying; it's just not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned in another post, annotation attributes must be constant.

Another approach could be getting an EntityManager instance programmatically:

```
Persistence.getEntityManagerFactory().getEntityManager(persistenceUnitName);
```

You could implement the logic necessary to assign the persistence unit name depending on your own criteria. Obviously this has all the downsides associated to the fact that persistence is not managed by the container anymore.

Comment: Thank you.

Obviously, I want to leave persistence context the relationship spring.

Comment: So you want to define at runtime what PersistenceContext you want to use and let Spring resolve it?

Comment: Piotr Nowicki, I want to defined at runtime PersistenceContext and to use and let Spring resolve it.

Comment: This code isn't quite right - the persistence unit name is an argument to getEntityManagerFactory, not getEntityManager. Also, i've only just seen that you suggested this; i had already added something similar to my answer. Not copying, honest!

Answer (score 0):

I reached a solutions. I'm new learning in Spring. There are definitely better solutions, but I still wanted to share the solution.

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring"/ 

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerConstant"/ 

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerRelative"/ 

<bean id="odev" class="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.entity.Nesne"  / 

<bean id="transactionManagerConstant" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="constant"/> 
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" /> 
</bean> 
<bean id="transactionManagerRelative" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="relative"/> 
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" /> 
</bean> 
<bean id="jpaDialect" 
class="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.util.HibernateExtendedJpaDialect" / 

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitMa nager"> 
<property name="persistenceXmlLocations"> 
  <list> 
      <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value> 
      <value>classpath*:META-INF/hk.xml</value> 
  </list> 
</property> 
</bean> 
<bean id="constant" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
<property name="persistenceUnitManager" 
ref="persistenceUnitManager" /> 
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JSFSpring" /> 
</bean> 
<bean id="relative" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
<property name="persistenceUnitManager" 
ref="persistenceUnitManager" /> 
</bean> 
<bean id="persistenceManager" 
class="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.util.PersistenceManager"/> 
</beans>
```

PersistenceManager.java

```
public class PersistenceManager { 
   private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean persistence; 
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getPersistence() { 
    return persistence; 
   } 

   @Autowired 
   @Qualifier("relative") 
   public void setPersistence(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
persistence) { 
    this.persistence = persistence; 
   } 
}
```

PersistDAO.java

```
@Component("persistDAO") 
@Scope("session") 
public class PersistDAO { 
   @PersistenceContext(unitName="JSFSpring") 
   private EntityManager em; 

   @Autowired 
   private PersistenceManager persistenceManager; 

   @Autowired 
   private Nesne nesne; 

   private List<Odev> kayitListesi; 
   private List<Event> eventListesi; 
   private String myUnit = "hakdogan"; 

   public Nesne getNesne() { 
     return nesne; 
   } 

   public void setNesne(Nesne nesne) { 
     this.nesne = nesne; 
   } 

   @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = 
    Propagation.REQUIRED) 
   public String kaydet(){ 
      em.persist(nesne); 
      return "/liste.xhtml"; 
   } 

   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true) 
   public List<Odev> getKayitListesi() { 
      return kayitListesi = (List<Odev>) 
      em.createNamedQuery("Odev.findAll").getResultList(); 
   } 

   @Transactional(readOnly=true) 
   public List<Event> getEventListesi() { 
      persistenceManager.getPersistence().setPersistenceUnitName(myUnit); 
      EntityManager emt =        persistenceManager.getPersistence().getNativeEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager(); 
    return eventListesi = (List<Event>) 
    emt.createNamedQuery("Event.findAll").getResultList(); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was not the solution :)

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerConstant"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerRelative"/>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.util.HibernateExtendedJpaDialect" />
<bean id="transactionManagerConstant" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="constant"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerRelative" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="relative"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="constant" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JSFSpring" />
</bean>

<bean id="relative" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hakdogan" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
   <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
   <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
   <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
   <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
   <list>
      <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceManager" class="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.util.PersistenceManager"/>
<bean id="odev" class="com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.entity.Odev" scope="prototype" />

</beans>
```

PersistenceManager.java:

```
public class PersistenceManager {


@Autowired
private LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean persistence;
private PersistenceProvider provider;

 public EntityManager getBaglam(String unitName){
    if(null == provider)
        provider = persistence.getPersistenceProvider();

    if(!unitName.equals(persistence.getPersistenceUnitName()))
        persistence.setPersistenceUnitName(unitName);

    return provider.createEntityManagerFactory(unitName, null).createEntityManager();
 }
}
```

PersistDAO.java:

```
@Component("persistDAO")
@Scope("session")
public class PersistDAO {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="JSFSpring")
   private EntityManager em;


@Autowired
private PersistenceManager persistenceManager;

private List<Odev> kayitListesi;
private List<Event> eventListesi;
private List<Musteriler> musteriListesi;    

private String myUnit = "hakdogan";


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true)
public List<Odev> getKayitListesi() {
    return kayitListesi = (List<Odev>) em.createNamedQuery("Odev.findAll").getResultList();
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<Event> getEventListesi() {
    return persistenceManager.getBaglam(myUnit).createQuery("SELECT e FROM Event e").getResultList();
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<Musteriler> getMusteriListesi() {
    return persistenceManager.getBaglam("musteri").createNamedQuery("Musteriler.findAll").getResultList();
}
}
```

Does not have a property such as LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean persistenceUnitManager. For this reason, I could not set the names of unit.

The cost is to create EntityManagerFactory in happening. Trying to slow the project.

I'm looking for an effective solution in the Spring.

Thanks.